# SharePoint 2010 Calendars

Tags: 2010, calendar

Recently I moved our room booking system to a simple online process - each room has it's own site containing only a web-part calendar.

Is there any way at all, to make sure that nobody can book any time slot in a certain day, if somebody has already booked an all-day event for that day?? A few people are struggling with this.

Yesterday I had an 8 hour meeting in one of our rooms. Had the meeting down on the calendar as an 'all-day event'. But, this didn't stop people from being able to book different slots through the day. Some people were failing to notice the all day booking banner underneath the date.

Comment: Pay attention to the form of your questions in future. This is a bit rude, but **nobody** here is interested in reading half a post about ones achievements during the SharePoint adventures of life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Removed original post, replaced with a non-programmatic solution

A very easy thing to do is simply enable content approval. Just approve the one you want to be visible, all the other ones will stay invisible for everyone except the original contributor.

You can also make a calculated field that goes true or false depending on if it's the first added meeting request for a specific day and use a filter on your calendar view to only show items that are true.